# Amount value regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I am trying to create a regular expression for a dollar amount that accepts values between 5.00 and 1000.00.

Here is what I have so far:

```
^([5-9](\d){0,4}([.](\d){1,2})?|1000([.](0){1,2})?)?$
```

I have already tried the range validator and it isn't working this field.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with, which could likely be improved.  It seems to work for my limited testing.  You may want to tag your question with "regex" to get some expert advice!

```
^(?:[5-9](?:\.\d{0,2})?|\d{2,3}(?:\.\d{0,2})?|1000(?:\.0{0,2})?)$
```